# Program runs perfectly in MPLAB but not load properly on PIC 32

Tags: c, pic32

I'm right now working with UART, Keyboard and LCD to interchange data as per user requirements in a single unit. Means User can select any Input and Output devices listed above as per the selection bits. The code and Output works perfectly fine when I debug using MPLAB X 3.50. I have a PIC32 development board and ICD3 as a loader, but when I try to load my code in to the PIC32 through ICD UART works perfectly fine but LCD print data like ???->->->->??.
when I disconnect entire board and connect it again I observe the UART output perfectly but LCD display like the above message.

Is there any idea ???\\

Comment: Debug build, JTAG debugger.  Get to work...

Comment: As we cannot verify the hardware is working correctly, it is hard to tell even iff we had a [mcve]. But the crystal ball tells me the error is is line xxx, module yyy.